# spring org.springframework.ui.Model initialization

Tags: spring-mvc, uiviewcontroller

I use spring and I'd like to configure my uiModel to return into my controller by a service.
But my question is: How can I initialize the model Variable?

following my code is post.
Thanks

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page/{idPage}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page(@PathVariable("idPage") long idPage, Model uiModel) {
    uiModel= pageService.modelForPage(idPage);
    return "page";
}
```

my service

```
public Model modelForPage(long idPage) {

  Model uiModel= ???
    // other lines for  some addAttribute
  return uiModel;

}
```

if I write Model uiModel = null; I have java.lang.NullPointerException;

Comment: What about passing the model to the service method?
`pageService.modelForPage(idPage, uiModel);`

Comment: @James yes...simple, tnx